# what these parenthesis in this require works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, require, parentheses

I have this code with the require function of NodeJS and I don't know how it works and what it exactly returns to the "sass" variable. What we archieve with the second require between parenthesis and how it connects with the first require? This question is more about what the second pair of parenthesis does.

```
const sass = require("gulp-sass")(require("sass"));
```

Comment: `require("gulp-sass")` returns a function. `require("sass")` returns another value. That value is passed to the function returned by `require("gulp-sass")`.

Comment: It's a normal function call. If you prefer you can rewrite it as `gulpSass = require('gulp-sass'); sass = gulpSass(require('sass'));`

Comment: @slebetman Perfect. Now I undestand. Thanks you both.